# Why would Linux syscall read() return less than the requested size?

Tags: file-io, linux-kernel, system-calls

On success, the `read(2)` system call returns the number of bytes read.
The man page says

> It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may  happen  for  example  because  fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.

To make sure you've read the full file, the solution is apparently to just call `read()` again, since a return of `0` always means EOF.  However, my question is for what reason besides receiving a signal might `read()` return fewer bytes **on a regular file**?
For regular files, how would being "close to end-of-file" make fewer bytes get read?

Comment: "For regular files, how would being "close to end-of-file" make fewer bytes get read?" - If a single byte remains in the file, and you request 4 bytes to read, then first `read()` call would return 1, and futher `read()` calls would return 0 (EOF).

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the documentation.  "we were close to end-of-file" means the file offset *before* (not after) calling `read()`.  Therefore for a regular file that did not receive a signal, if you request N bytes and `read()` returns  M < N, then **it is safe to conclude that EOF has been reached** (unless the file is modified in the meantime).

Comment: "`read()` returns M < N, then it is safe to conclude that EOF has been reached" - This could be true in the most cases, but filesystems (even regular ones) are free to violate that. So, if you want to safely read a file till the end, you need to call `read` until it returns 0, not until it returns less than requested.

Comment: That makes sense.  If I understand you correctly, there's no reason a regular file would return M < N except EOF, but this behavior is not guaranteed by the standard.